# diamond-operator is used for two entirely different concepts

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

I just saw that [diamond-operator](/questions/tagged/diamond-operator) seems to be used (in roughly equal parts) for two entirely different things that share a name:

- the Perl diamond operator
- The [diamond `<>` introduced in Java 7](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/gentypeinference.html#type-inference-instantiation)

While `<>` in Java is not strictly speaking an operator, it is often described as such.

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: so what do they call it in Java 7?

Comment: I thought this was gonna be a post about moderators. =)

Comment: @LanceRoberts: the tutorial "simply" calls it "empty set of type parameters (`<>`)" and adds "This pair of angle brackets is informally called the *diamond*.". Unfortunately I can't find the Java Language Specification for Java 7 so I can't check if there is a technically correct term for it.

Comment: Simple rule of thumb: If it is not an operator, don't tag it as operator.

Comment: @PaddedCell: I tend to agree with you, but it seems that the term "diamond operator" is already deeply seated in the Java community. In unrelated news: I'm not sure that the *Perl* diamond operator is an operator. But I don't know enough about Perl to be sure.

Comment: Had the same issue with [MVVM], which is used to describe a pattern used in both [WPF] and [KnockoutJS].

Answer (score 8):

Just use the [diamond-operator](/questions/tagged/diamond-operator) and the language tag with it will show which one is referred to.

Otherwise you'ld have to create the [perl-diamond-operator](/questions/tagged/perl-diamond-operator) and [java-diamond-operator](/questions/tagged/java-diamond-operator), and that seems a little over the top for such a special use case.

Answer (score 3):

I'd edit the tag excerpt to explain the ambiguity. Something like

> The term "diamond operator" is ambiguous. In Perl, the diamond operator `<>` provides an easy way to read input from files specified on command line. In Java, the diamond operator `<>` allows you to invoke the constructor of a generic class with an empty set of type parameters as long as the compiler can infer the type arguments from the context.

The same is done on a few tags, like [datatable](/questions/tagged/datatable).
If necessary, suggest along to include the relevant language tag.

Comment: Maybe a little shorter for the excerpt, with your paragraph in the main text.